# Copying arrays of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

This is something I haven't done before and want to know what the proper methodology should be

If you had a trivial object such as:

```
struct simple_object {
    int i;
};
```

And in your application you created an array of these objects of the form:

```
simple_object *array = new simple_object[10];
```

I know that the default behaviour of c++ is to allocate the array and call the default constructor of this class on each object, and similarly the destructor will be called on each for `delete [] array`.

The question comes up when you want to increase the size of the array. For instance if you wanted to double the size of the array you might do something like:

```
simple_object *temp = new simple_object[20];
memcpy(temp, array, sizeof (simple_object) * 10);
delete [] array;
array = temp;
```

But I think this is dangerous and probably won't even work anyway (there would probably be some conflicts in a destructor of a more complicated object). Another option would be:

```
simple_object *temp = new simple_object[20];
for (i to 10)
{
   temp[i] = array[i];
}
delete [] array;
array = temp;
```

That way every element in the array is default constructed and the copy constructor for each object is called directly. Is this the proper way to copy arrays of objects or are there other more standard ways to do it?

I know that the standard option would be to use a vector and utilize it's resizing capabilities but instead of the boilerplate answer I'd like to better understand what the proper operation for copying arrays of objects should be

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: In your last example the copy constructor is not called, the copy-assignment operator is. Since you are deleting the original array after the copy [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) may come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing this at all, you should probably do about like `std::vector` does. It allocates raw memory with `operator new` (via an allocator). Then it uses `placement new` to create items in that memory.

When it needs to move an object it will use move assignment/construction by preference. If that's not available it'll copy then destroy the old ones.

Either way, it won't default construct objects like an array would.

Answer (score 0):

Working with (dynamic length) raw arrays you can use `std::copy` to copy items. It's equivalent to using a loop, except that it may be optimized for the cases where it can safely invoke e.g. `memcpy` to do the job. I.e., safe, and efficient where it can be.

You can also use the [`std::move` *algorithm*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) to move items from the array-to-be-deleted. I am less sure of the exception safety issues there, however, that is, what to do if an exception occurs doing moving say half way through. I think it would be rather difficult to recover from that, but I have not used this, i.e. I haven't delved into it, really, and so it's just my impression.

But it's much simpler to just use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

It takes care of memory management and copying.